# HTML: Unexpected Bootstrap layout (singin template)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I'm trying to learn [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and I started creating a login page.

First in my `html` file I added Bootstrap external resources like Javascript and CSS as show [here](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/).

Then I just copied the [Singin Template for Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/) source code in my page.

The problem is that **what I got is different from the original Bootstrap page**. Mine is pressed and hasn't the same layout.

Here is code snippet showing my page:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Bootstrap css -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- Bootstrap js -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-KXn5puMvxCw+dAYznun+drMdG1IFl3agK0p/pqT9KAo= sha512-2e8qq0ETcfWRI4HJBzQiA3UoyFk6tbNyG+qSaIBZLyW9Xf3sWZHN/lxe9fTh1U45DpPf07yj94KsUHHWe4Yk1A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="" autofocus="">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
          </label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**How can I solve that? Am I missing something?**

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more to the example you linked to that the HTML and the basic Bootstrap stylesheet.

It also loads another CSS file which sets various heights, widths, padding, and so on.

[image: Screenshot of source]